# Error 1064 importing field time from Excel

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import data to MySQL from excel, using the "MysQL from Excel" tool. No problem in general, but when I tryed to import a time field I got the following error msg:

Error while appending rows...

MySQL Error 1064:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ':30:00,15:00:00,'HL091','82818008','82818008')' at line 4

In my excel sheet I have the following:

```
Field1    Field2  Field3    Field4    Field5
82818008  HL091   82818008  7:30:00   15:00:00
```

"Field4" and "Field5" are defined like a "Time" in the Mysql table

I noticed that in the msg error the data of the "Field4" appears truncated (":30:00" instead of "7:30:00") and that the problem is at line 4 instead of line 1 (the only line that I'm trayng to import from excel while the problem is unsolved)

Any idea what can I do for solve it
Thanks a Lot !

Comment: without seeing your original file it is hard to make comment.

Comment: Hi Simonare, thanks for reading me. Please tell me what extra information do you would like to see, I just copied the information that I thought was enough

Comment: check the erranous cell's data type first. you may try to save your excel as csv to see if there is something uncommon